# whats this error mean (in xcode)? [NSUnknownKeyException]

Tags: xcode, runtime-error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key butp.'

where is my problem?

Comment: There is no way for someone to know **where** the problem is without seeing some code...

Comment: Look at the list of related questions to yours. There are countless existing questions covering this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your references of your outlets in your XIB, one of them is probably referencing a property (butp) that does not exist anymore

Comment: thanks. my problem solved :) I just deleted the extra button's Outlet (butp)!